# Optimize mysql query (use or create index)

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I have a SQL request (mySQL 5.1.51) that makes PHP timeout.
I would like to optimize it but I can't find what is missing.
The request is :

```
SELECT s_i.incident,
       s.hostname,
       a.application,
       s_ie.problem_status,
       s_i.open_time,
       s_i.close_time,
       s_ie.open_group,
       s_ie.primary_assignment,
       s_ie.closed_by_group,
       s_ie.contact_first_name,
       s_ie.contact_last_name,
       s_ie.description,
       s_ie.resolution,
       s_ie.famille_1,
       s_ie.famille_2,
       s_ie.famille_3,
       YEARWEEK(s_i.open_time)              AS 'semaine_ouverture',
       DATE_FORMAT(s_i.open_time,  '%Y-%m') AS 'mois_ouverture',
       YEARWEEK(s_i.close_time)             AS 'semaine_cloture',
       DATE_FORMAT(s_i.close_time, '%Y-%m') AS 'mois_cloture',
       p.nom,
       s.exploite_par,
       t.environnement,
       a.tdb
FROM t_link_serveur_eac t USE KEY(nna)
     INNER JOIN serveur          s    ON s.id            = t.id_serveur
     INNER JOIN plateau          p    ON p.id            = t.id_plateau
     INNER JOIN applications     a    ON a.nna           = t.nna
     INNER JOIN scope_i          s_i  USE KEY (id_serveur) ON s_i.id_serveur  = t.id_serveur
     INNER JOIN scope_i_extended s_ie USE KEY (id_scope_i) ON s_ie.id_scope_i = s_i.id
WHERE s_ie.problem_status     = 'Closed'
AND   s_ie.contact_first_name = 'AUTOMATE'
AND   s_ie.contact_last_name LIKE '%BEM%'
AND   p.id           = 4
AND   open_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 52 WEEK AND open_time <= CURDATE()
AND   AND s_i.close_time < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY
ORDER BY mois_cloture
```

When I ask mySQL to explain it, I have a line type 'ALL' for the union of the table s_ie.
I tried to create/modify all possibles index but all my tried didn't make any difference :

```
id  select_type   table   type    possible_keys   key        key_len  ref                  rows   Extra
1   SIMPLE        p       const   PRIMARY         PRIMARY    4        const                 1     Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE        a       ALL     PRIMARY         NULL       NULL     NULL                  957
1   SIMPLE        t       ref     nna             nna        26       inspire.a.nna         10    Using where
1   SIMPLE        s       eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY    4        inspire.t.id_serveur  1
1   SIMPLE        s_i     ref     id_serveur      id_serveur 4        inspire.t.id_serveur  135   Using where
1   SIMPLE        s_ie    eq_ref  id_scope_i      id_scope_i 4        inspire.s_i.id        1     Using where
```

s_ie has 712.000 lines and s_i 740.000 so I think that the problem comes from this junction

Here is the structure of the table s_ie

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scope_i_extended` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_scope_i` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `problem_status` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `open_group` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `primary_assignment` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `closed_by_group` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `contact_first_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `contact_last_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `resolution` text NOT NULL,
  `famille_1` text NOT NULL,
  `famille_2` text NOT NULL,
  `famille_3` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_scope_i` (`id_scope_i`),
  UNIQUE KEY `problem_status` (`id_scope_i`, `problem_status`, `contact_first_name`, `contact_last_name`),
  KEY `contact_last_name` (`contact_last_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the structure of s_i

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scope_i` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `incident` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `statut` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_serveur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `open_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `close_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `affectation` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `titre` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `incident` (`incident`),
  KEY `serveur` (`id_serveur`),
  KEY `serveur_open_time` (`id_serveur`,`open_time`),
  KEY `id_serveur` (`id_serveur`,`close_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=738862 ;
```

May you help/save me?

Regards,

Olivier

Comment: post the query execution plan as well please

Comment: just edit the question and put it there, do not try to add output in comments

Comment: Indeed, comments cannot be formatted onto make an execution plan correctly readable. I edited the question an added it.

Comment: You are ordering records by a calculated field (mois_cloture). Try removing the ORDER BY clause and notice the query execution time. It will probably be significantly lower. Also, if your result set is as big as you state in one of your comments (30,000+ records) the client receiving and buffering will certainly create a delay as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for stating the obvious but I'd suggest using: 
`"YEARWEEK(open_time) <= '201246' AND YEARWEEK(open_time) >= '201146'"`

instead of 
`"YEARWEEK(open_time) IN (...)"`

IN always slows things dramatically.

Comment: Indeed, that's a point that I saw and I will ask the developper to optimize this part as well (waybe with BETWEEN also)

Comment: @Olivier Gérault  You might want to toss this link at the dev: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates

Comment: Thanks, I read it and applied the suggestions but still the execution fail in PHP because of timeout.

Answer (score 1):

In your condition, you have date columns wrapped within a Mysql Function.
ex: `YEARWEEK(open_time)` and `DATE_FORMAT(s_i.close_time, '%Y-%m-%d')`
You should avoid this since Mysql seems to execute the function for each row of the table.

Can you try to replace

`DATE_FORMAT(s_i.close_time, '%Y-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01')`

by

`s_i.close_time < CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY`

and

`YEARWEEK(open_time) IN ('201246', '201245'....)`

by this: (below is condition to get all records has "open_time" within a year. I am not sure if it's your case)

`open_time >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND open_time <= CURDATE()`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I applied them and it makes me save execution time (1.5s vs 1.08s). Nevertheless, it still fail. I forgot to say that the result is an array of 31.000 lines